# How to make check_estimator() work for multi-output estimators?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

scikit-learn's check_estimator() calls check_supervised_y_2d() which checks that when a 2D y is given, a DataConversionWarning is raised. My estimator supports multi-outputs, so 2D y is naturally supported. How can I use check_estimator with a multi-output estimator?

Comment: Work around: in my test script I added my estimator to MULTI_OUTPUT in estimator_checks.py ... from sklearn.utils.estimator_checks import MULTI_OUTPUT;  MULTI_OUTPUT.append('<my estimator>')

Comment: In scikit-learn 0.21.2 MultiOutputMixin is provided by base.py and takes proper care of multi-outputs!

Comment: You saved me. That Mixin isn't even in the documentation yet, but sure enough there it is in `base.py`, and importing and inheriting from it in [my code](https://github.com/pavelkomarov/projection-pursuit/blob/master/skpp/skpp.py) allows my class to pass `check_estimator()`. Unfortunately it also breaks compatibility with older versions of sklearn.